# Finding smallest and largest possible value of $E[XY]$

Tags: probability, expected-value

> Let $P(X=1)=P(X=2)=P(Y=1)=P(Y=2)=\frac{1}{2}$.
> Find the smallest and largest possible value of $E[XY]$.

My solution:

If $X$, $Y$ are independent, then $E[XY] = (\frac{3}{2})^2 = \frac{9}{4}$.
Now, let's assume they are dependent in such a way:

1. If $X=1$ then $Y=1$ and if $X=2$ then $Y=2$, then $E[XY] = \frac{1}{2}\cdot 1 \cdot 1 +  \frac{1}{2}\cdot 2 \cdot 2 = \frac{5}{2}$.
2. If $X=1$ then $Y=2$ and if $X=2$ then $Y=1$, then $E[XY] = \frac{1}{2}\cdot 1 \cdot 2 +  \frac{1}{2}\cdot 2 \cdot 1 = 2$.

Hence, $2 \leq E[XY] \leq \frac{5}{2}$

Is this a correct answer?

Comment: Kind of. You still need to consider non absolute dependency and prove that they give results within the range.

Comment: You have shown that $2$ and $\frac52$ are possible values of $E[XY]$ but I think you need more to prove they are the most extreme possible values.  Using the correlation being in $[-1,1]$ might be one way if you already know that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have only shown that $E[XY]$ can attain the values $2$ and $2.5$, but you have not shown that $E[XY]$ is always in the interval $[2,2.5]$. Here is one way to complete the proof.

Let $p=P(X=1\wedge Y=1)$. Since
$$
1/2=P(X=1)=P(X=1\wedge Y=1)+P(X=1\wedge Y=2),
$$
we conclude that $P(X=1\wedge Y=2)=1/2-p$. Similarly, you can show
$$
P(X=2\wedge Y=1)=1/2-p,\qquad P(X=2\wedge Y=2)=p.
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
E[XY]
&=p\cdot (1\cdot1)+(1/2-p)\cdot (1\cdot 2)+(1/2-p)\cdot (2\cdot 1)+p\cdot (2\cdot 2)
\\&=p+2(1-2p)+4p=2 + p
\end{align}$$
Since $0\le p\le 1/2$, we conclude that $2\le E[XY] \le 2+1/2$, as desired.

Comment: A nice solution!